# Ошибки при извлечении элементов из array

Tags: php, массивы, for

В цикле `for` не выводит данные из массивов.

Кусочек кода:

```
$arr = [
[
    'name' => 'John',
    'age' => 20],
[
    'name' => 'Andrey',
    'age' => 23],
[
    'name' => 'Sergey',
    'age' => 32],
[
    'name' => 'Vik',
    'age' => 37],
[
    'name' => 'Lily',
    'age' => 25]
];

shuffle($arr);

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    echo $arr['name'][$i];
    echo $arr['age'][$i];
}
```

Выводит ошибку

```
Notice: Undefined index: name
Notice: Undefined index: age
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: `$arr[$i]['name']` и `$arr[$i]['age']` P.S. Почему бы не использовать `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте индексы местами:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    echo $arr[$i]['name'];
    echo $arr[$i]['age'];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: А как будет с foreach или while? Я нуб в этом. С for все работает.

Comment: `foreach ($arr as $ar) { echo $ar['name']; echo $ar['age']; }`

Comment: Нужно добавить $i = 2; до foreach и $i++;  внутри foreach. Все понял. Спасибо всем:)